# How is a skeletal implementation different from an ordinary abstract class?

Tags: java, class, interface, abstract

In *Effective Java*, Joshua Bloch favors interfaces over abstract classes. However, he notes that a skeletal implementation should come with every interface.

I feel that a skeletal implementation is almost the same as an abstract class. How do these two concepts differ?

Comment: For _every_ interface? Could you give a page reference of this statement?

Comment: One sentence might clear the confusion. Quoting from the book:
"The beauty of skeletal implementation classes is that they provide all of the implementation assistance of abstract classes without imposing the severe constraints that abstract classes impose when they serve as type definitions"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sup>Edited after re-reading the aforementioned section in *Effective Java*</sup>

[According to this section of the book](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA97&lpg=PA97&dq=Joshua%20Bloch%20skeletal%20implementation&source=bl&ots=yYGfNls3P_&sig=vB9KLxwP0NXGnPoysh21zNhIqeQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kY_nT5K-IJSo8gTygMmvAQ&ved=0CMsBEOgBMAY#v=onepage&q&f=false) a skeletal implementation *is* an abstract class.  He recommends this approach because, after a skeletal implementation is in place, it becomes trivial to implement the interface and selectively override methods, even with an anonymous class (as he does in his book).

---

<sup>Previous answer, edited slightly for continuity</sup>

A skeletal implementation could theoretically be a complete implementation and therefore concrete.  Then it could be used with [composition](http://tiedyedfreaks.org/eric/CompositionVsInheritance.html), because it can be instantiated.  Whereas abstract classes *require* inheritance.

Answer (score 4):

What he means is that you should provide an interface, and an abstract class implementing parts of this interface:

```
public interface Foo {
    void bar();
    void baz();
}

private abstract class AbstractFoo implements Foo {
    ...
}
```

The `AbstractFoo` class may even not be abstract if it's possible to provide a basic, complete implementation. But if you need a class that is a Foo, but can't extend AbstractFoo, it's still possible with an interface. An abstract class doesn't provide this capability, since you can only extend one class.

BTW, this is what is done in the collections framework (which Josh Bloch created): the `Set` interface is implemented by `AbstractSet`, the `List` interface is implemented by `AbstractList`, etc.

Comment: How is this any better than just starting off with `AbstractFoo`? Wouldn't `DerivedFoo` still need to extend `AbstractFoo`?

Answer (score 2):

The interface / abstract class is part of the API.

The skeletal implementation is a valid concrete `class`, but a limited / naïve / poor implementation; for (a very contrived) example, a skeletal implementation of a `Sorter` interface might implement [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) - you wouldn't want to use it in a production application, but it illustrates how one might implement the interface

Answer (score 2):

> I feel that a skeletal implementation is almost the same as an
>   abstract class. How do these two concepts differ?

To me, they differ in *intent*.  When I see some method expects an interface to be passed in, I know that the implementation is up to me.  If a class is returned, I'm no longer sure.  There's simply a *meaning* to the use of an interface that doesn't exist for a class.

Also, methods that accept classes for arguments invite conflict when the class we'd like to pass in is already a subclass; Java doesn't support multiple inheritance.  Interfaces don't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A "skeletal implementation" is a concrete class: you can compile and test it.

An abstract class isn't, and you can't ;)

Comment: -1 You can compile every properly formed class. Skeletal implementation is an abstract class.

Comment: Dude, a "skeletal implementation" is NOT necessarily an abstract class.

Comment: I downvoted your answer mainly because of "you can compile". It is an abstract class in refered book. That's what I meant.